# parameter passing between two classes in two different files

Tags: php, oop

i want to ask how to pass parameter between two classes in two different files?
ex:

```
class a{
  function aa(){
    $var1 = 10;
    return $var1;
  }
}
//in different file
class b{
  function bb(){
    echo"$var1"; //how this can be achieved?
  }
}
```

Comment: Instantiate class `a` and call the function `aa` from from the function `bb` in class `b`

Comment: Yup. how are they related. it does not make good programming sense to directly access the variable of one class in another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the answers here are right, since the op is asking to **pass the parameter** and not call it. The correct way to do it, is by creating an object of class b

```
class a{
  function aa(){
    $var = 10;
    $obj_b = new b(); //create an object of the class b
    $b -> bb($var); //pass the $var value to bb method of class b
  }
}

//in different file
class b{
  function bb($var){
    echo $var;  //now your values is passed here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

within the function `bb` do this :

```
include('filepath to the file containing class a');
$a = new a();
echo a->aa();
```

or look at making the `aa` function static

Note: your variable in class `a` is `$var` and you return `$var1`

And a good place to start learning about Classes and Objects in PHP is here -> http://uk.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Answer (score 1):

You can call the function with the class name but both classes must be loaded in the script.

```
class b{
function bb(){
     echo $var1 = a::aa(); 
   }
}
```

you should return `$var` instead of `$var1` in the method `aa`

Answer (score 1):

```
class a{
  function aa(){
    $var = 10;
    return $var1;
  }
}
//in different file
class b{
  $aobj = new a();
    $var1 = $aobj ->aa();
    echo"$var1"; //this can be achieved
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or with a [static method](http://es2.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php):

```
class A {
    public static function aa(){
        $var = 10;
        return $var1;
    }
}
```

Then you could call anywhere:

```
A::aa()
```

Just make sure that the script that defines class A is loaded before you call it (duh!)